# respond_to route to a partial fails, using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have several partials in a page.  A user can provide partial information (short_form) that's matched to all the information we have on file.  They're then redirected to a different form (long_form) that's been completed for verification.  Unfortunately, the routing breaks:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render '/users/user_dashboard/_pending'}
end
```

The form "_pending" is in the shared folder: /shared/_pending

It's preceded on the user_dashboard page by several other partials, e.g., ones with family members' information.  The routing "stalls" at the first partial with the error "Missing template users/user_dashboard/_pending  I'm not, incidentally, specifying a url in the form_for block.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The main view that needs to be rendered is `/users/users_dashboard.html.erb`, right? And that internally calls all the partials, including `_pending`, correct? If that is the case, you should have `render '/users/user_dashboard`. The way it is specified now, it will look for a file called `app/views/users/user_dashboard/_pending.html.erb`

Comment: If I direct it to '/users/user_dashboard', it stalls at the first partial with this error message: ' Missing partial events/_family_1 '.  The input forms are in a users / views folder.  The partials in a shared folder.  The data is managed by the events controller and corresponding model. I suspect I need to move the forms to the shared folder and / or move the matching algorithm to the users controller?  I'm trying to avoid "nesting."  Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest reading up http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html to get a better understanding.

Comment: If you would show your forms it would be easier to help you.

Comment: @Beartech I didn't because they're extremely long.  Here's the error message using this route in the Event controller:  `format.html {render 'users/user_dashboard' }` gives this error: `Missing partial events/_family_1, application/_family_1 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}`  That's the first partial it hits on the user_dashboard page, not the second (the pending partial).  I've now also tried placing content_for around the correct section of the page with no luck.  Any direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the code up on github? Just kind of shooting in the dark without being able to see more. You say they are in a "shared" folder. How is it shared? What does your routes file look like? You can put your form up, even if it's long. If you want an answer from the community, you need to put show a little more effort. This is obviously a complex setup, rather hard to troubleshoot with so little info.

Comment: @Beartech  I re-asked / posted the question as SO # 27810731 with the full code.  The problem is in the rendering page header - using class form-inline and class form.  Apparently, you can't nest forms.  Removing one fixed the issue.  Thanks for your help with this.